# Iphone Upload String to FTP server

Tags: iphone, ios5

I need to simply upload a STRING to an ftp server of mine as a txt, i searched well and nothing is working. Is there anyway of simply uploading the string to the ftp server?
NOTE: i have looked at s7ftp thing simpleftp and the ftp thing from apple i could not get anything to work.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

Can you create a server-side script to parse a POST/GET string?  Seems like uploading a file could be a lot of heavy lifting/coding for something you could do in 3 lines server-side.  Just an idea.

**Edited addition**

Here's some simple Objective-C you can poke around with:

```
// Create the request.
NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.YOURDOMAIN.com/?string=YOURSTRINGORWHATEVER"]
                        cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                    timeoutInterval:60.0];
// create the connection with the request
// and start loading the data
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
if (theConnection) {
    // Create the NSMutableData to hold the received data.
    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
} else {
    // Inform the user that the connection failed.
}
```

[Click here for more info on URL Loading](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html)

If you can't use ARC or are having troubles with it, try this class.  Pretty handy:

[SMWebRequest Class on GitHub](https://github.com/nfarina/webrequest)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is exactly what I would do. It is extremely easy to do in PHP using the [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) variable.

Comment: i cant even send the string as is.

Comment: Ok i can do a server side code, but i cant send anything to the server. any ideas???

Comment: ARC forbids explicit message send of 'retain'
Its giving me this error.

Comment: Thanks but the SMWebRequest had nothing to do with my situation.

Comment: Um, what you're wanting to do is a HTTP request, it's exactly your situation. Not really sure what else to say or how else to help at this point.